# Error building docker image while trying to import sql dump to postgres container

Tags: postgresql, shell, docker, containers, dockerfile

I'm making a Dockerfile for an application that connects to a postgres container inside the same docker network. To populate the database, inside the Dockerfile I first install the postgres client and all the dependencies and then try to execute the sql dump like this:

```
RUN apt-get install python python-dev libpq-dev postgresql-client
RUN psql -h $SQL_HOST -U $SQL_USER -W $SQL_DB < some_dump.sql
```

I get this error:

```
The command '/bin/sh -c psql -h $SQL_HOST -U $SQL_USER -W $SQL_DB < some_dump.sql' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

The variable $SQL_HOST has the name of the docker container, which I can ping postgres with no problem.

When I manually set up the container, I can execute with no problem the following:

```
psql -h $SQL_HOST -U $SQL_USER 
postgres=#
```

Or even this:

```
/bin/sh 
> psql -h $SQL_HOST -U $SQL_USER
postgres=#
```

But I get an error when I try to connect to postgres (I'm guessing) the way docker does when building the image:

```
/bin/sh -c psql -h $SQL_HOST -U $SQL_USER
```

Error message:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Any ideas of why I get this error? My guesses were that the env vars were not available in the /bin/sh shell, but it's not the case. I even pinged  postgres inside the /bin/sh shell and succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

It was pretty obvious, docker can't identify hosts of other containers when building the image, it is until you execute the `docker run --net <network>` that you can communicate with other containers.